# How to pass values from Silverlight (Xaml) application to Asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I am doing an application in Silverlight in which I should pass the values in xaml to asp.net page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used `Uri` Class to send parameter to asp.net.

This code written on Silverlight Button Click Event.

```
Uri myURI = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri,String.Format("Report.aspx?brcd=   {0}&acc={1}&user={2}", Brcd, Acc, User)); HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myURI, "_blank");
```

Explanation of above code:

1. Reports/Report.aspx is my asp.net web form name. if your forms inside  folder just add folder name like this(Reports/Report.aspx...)
2. in method I write Brcd is user defined name and no need to define this name.
3. but  after comma Brcd is variable name define in silverlight page.
4. next line code just open new tab in browser and call uri me

Below code is written on Asp.net page_load or page init event

```
 Brcd = Request.QueryString["brcd"]; // brcd value accept here.
 acc = Request.QueryString["ACC"];
 user = Request.QueryString["User"];
```

In above code we accept the silverlight parameter in asp.net but in `[]` bracket put name as it is use in silverlight page because it case sensitive.